# How Do I Keep Up In Level As Support

Tags: league-of-legends

I usually play support, and it's often the case that by the time I'm level 13 or 14, everyone else is 16 or more. What's the best strategy for keeping up in level with everyone else?

Comment: You may be spending too much time going back and forth to base for potions/wards. If your team is doing well but you personally are "under leveled" as support, you are probably doing just fine though. Without more information, I can't really give an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to keep up in levels with everyone else. Keeping up in levels is very advantageous because typically utility abilities that support characters have become significantly better or more useful when they are a higher rank. Particularly on the cooldown reductions a rank up on a skill can add.

Getting the minion kill does not grant more experience to the person that got the last hit, it is evenly distributed. It is definitely a priority that your teammates have higher levels than the other team, but if you're behind in levels you start to become a liability.

Stay in lane as long as you can. You will fall behind slightly if you are warding correctly, so that is inevitable. However you need to be in lane as often as you can to get experience. Try to go back less and stay in lane more. It also helps to understand exactly how experience gain works in the game, [which is outlined in the League Of Legends Wiki.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28champion%29)

Being level 11 when your opponent is level 10 is a bigger advantage than most people think, you are right to be concerned with this problem.

Comment: I agree, but I think @StixVaria is right when he says that the trade-offs made are worth the lower level.

Comment: I agree that the trade-offs are worth it, but I don't think "As a support, you want to be a lower level" is a true statement. It also doesn't answer the question of "What is the best strategy to keep up in levels?"

Comment: "Stay in lane as long as you can. You will fall behind slightly if you are warding correctly, so that is inevitable. However you need to be in lane as often as you can to get experience. Try to go back less and stay in lane more." Exactly. A huge skill comes in knowing how to time wards to be BOTH: a) safe, and b) experience-efficient (b can be increased by a smart ADC who doesn't push when his support is out of lane if he can help it!)

Comment: While keeping up in levels is indeed desirable, "stay line lane as long as you can" is VERY poor advice and is not what is done at high level play.  In fact, Boots of Mobility (before their nerf) were a somewhat common buy for supports in Diamond/pro play because supports roamed so much out of their lane.  The idea being that supports could sometimes afford to roam and make plays in mid/jungle for the team while the ADC was farming.  That support sacrificing a bit of xp is often worth it for the overall health of the team.

Comment: In fact, one of the most common mistakes that people make is to stay in lane too long. The other team groups as 3 players or so (often something like mid/jungle/support) and achieves team objectives, while the other team stays static in their lane.  The team that groups will be way ahead in most cases.  Or, to put it another way, the hallmark of high level play is not to have people stay in lane for a long time - its people leaving lane and making team plays remarkably early compared to say, bronze level play.  I think that the poster probably realizes this, but it should probably be said here

Comment: I assume that this is a solo queue question he asks, in which case a roaming bottom lane is as unwise as it is rare. Bottom lane should be focused on or taking dragon at the right opportunity or (at most) supporting their jungler deny enemy jungle buffs. All of this is of course early-mid game, but the principle of trying to be in lane to gain experience still pervades into the late-game.

Comment: I agree that early game is probably too early for a support to be roaming, but by the mid game the support should not necessarily be static in their lane at all.  By that point they should be able to roam as far as mid in some cases for brief periods.  Certainly by the late game they should not be following a principle of sitting in a lane to gain experience - by that point the support's only real concern is to support the team in achieving team objectives, rather than to gain xp for themself.

Comment: That is correct, no question. Objectives should always take priority over experience, period. But I believe a good support is aware that their utility is also dependent on getting rank 3 in the abilities they prioritize, and therefore need to find ways to get exp.

Answer (score 0):

As a support, you don't *want* to keep up in level with everyone else. That's the point.

Support characters are those that are good at helping their teammates be as effective as possible even without as much gold or experience as everyone else. If you're doing your job right, your lane partner should get more gold and experience than you do. You don't want to give up *all* the experience, because you still want to level up your skills, but it's much more important for your carry to get to a high level than it is for you to get to a high level.

It sounds like you may actually be playing correctly already. The support gives up all the minion kills in the lane for his carry, and gives up all hero kills if possible for his carry (although securing the kill at all is more important than feeding your ally).

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say you dont *want* to keep up in level, but rather you don't need to keep up in level

Comment: This is misleading... you absolutely want to keep up in levels. You think your Leona will be effective if you're 3-4 levels below their mid or top? You think your Lulu will be effective if you're lvl10 during a lvl11+ teamfight (where ppl have rank2 ults)? Totally misleading. Supports CAN and DO fall behind, but it's by as little as possible because it's by no means desirable or a sign that you're playing well. As for your carry getting high level -- he's only gonna have a good laning experience if you're there with him. Any competent duo lane will zone a supportless ADC from CS, end of story.

Comment: Some other info here is also misleading... The support having levels is usually more important than the adc having levels.  The adc's usefulness comes about 90% from items while the supports usefulness comes about 50% from items and about 50% from level.  Typically the support will drop a little bit behind because of warding and such, but that doesn't mean you should be purposefully giving your adc levels.  The support carry's the lane and so it's important they have the levels to continue to carry until laning ends.